# JS Regex to match number with only one comma

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find out all numbers with exactly one comma. I've got this regex,

```
[\d ,]+
```

but it matches all numbers no matter how much commas is in the number.

So, in this text

```
lorem 49 877 989 888,33 ipsum 1,2,3 dfgdfgdf 1,222
```

it should match only first and last number:

```
49 877 989 888,33 
1,222
```

and NOT this

```
1,2,3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
\b(?<!\d,)(?:\d{1,3}(?: \d{3})*|\d+),\d+\b(?!,\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qE5UpD/4).

```js
const text = "lorem 49 877 989 888,33 ipsum 1,2,3 dfgdfgdf 1,222";
console.log(text.match(/\b(?<!\d,)(?:\d{1,3}(?: \d{3})*|\d+),\d+\b(?!,\d)/g));
```

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?<!\d,)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a digit and a comma immediately to the left of the current location
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `\d{1,3}` - one to three digits
  - `(?: \d{3})*` - zero or more repetitions of a space and three digits (replace the space with `\s` to match any whitespace chars)
  - `|` - or
  - `\d+` - any one or more digits
- `,` - a comma
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!,\d)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a comma and a digit immediately to the right of the current location.

If you do not want to use a regex with a lookbehind so that the pattern could be used in old/legacy browsers, use a common workaround:

```
(\d,)?\b(?:\d{1,3}(?: \d{3})*|\d+),\d+\b(?!,\d)
```

and filter out all matches where Group 1 is not empty. See [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/qE5UpD/3).

```js
var text = "lorem 49 877 989 888,33 ipsum 1,2,3 dfgdfgdf 1,222";
var regex = /(\d,)?\b(?:\d{1,3}(?: \d{3})*|\d+),\d+\b(?!,\d)/g;
var results = [], m;
while (m = regex.exec(text)) {
  if (m[1] === undefined) results.push(m[0])
}
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use an approach with two regex patterns.  First match on:

```
\b\d+(?:[ ,]?\d+)*\b
```

And then filter on only numbers with at most one comma.

Sample script:

```js
var input = "lorem 49 877 989 888,33 ipsum 1,2,3 dfgdfgdf 1,222";
var nums = input.match(/\b\d+(?:[ ,]?\d+)*\b/g)
                .filter(x => !x.match(/,.*,/));
console.log(nums);
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents using zero width lookbehind:

```
(?<!\d\s*,?)\d+(?:\s\d+)*,\d+(?!,?\s*\d)
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/5LGAwr/1)

---

- `(?<!\d\s*,?)` - Assert position is not preceded by a digit with 0+ space chars and an optional comma;
- `\d+(?:\s\d+)*,\d+` - Match 1+ digits, an non-capture group matched 0+ times to allow for space delimited numbers before matching a comma and 1+ more digits;
- `(?!,?\s*\d)` - Assert position is not followed by an optional comma, 0+ whitespace chars and another digit.

```js
var s_in = "lorem 49 877 989 888,33 ipsum 1,2,3 dfgdfgdf 1,222";
var s_out = s_in.match(/(?<!\d\s*,?)\d+(?:\s\d+)*,\d+(?!,?\s*\d)/g);
console.log(s_out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't do it in one line code, this is my solution:

```
let input = 'lorem 49 877 989 888,33 ipsum 1,2,3 dfgdfgdf 1,222'

let numbers = []
let words = input.split(/\s+/)
words.forEach(function(w)
{
        let nums = w.match(/\d+(?:[,\d]+)?/)
        if(nums)
        {
                let commas = nums[0].match(/,/g)
                if(commas)
                        commas = commas.length
                else
                        commas = 0
                if(commas<2)
                        numbers.push(nums[0])
        }
})

console.log(numbers)
```

Output:

```
[ '49', '877', '989', '888,33', '1,222' ]
```

Comment: Doesn't this give too many results? OP is looking for exactly 1 comma in a number that is potentially delimited by spaces, hence the attempts with `[\d ,]+` and the description in the 1st line of the question, right?

Comment: With this `it should match only first and last number:

49 877 989 888,33 
1,222
` I understand the desired matches are these